# odometry and gyro replacement for my new robot using smart-phone or tablet?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, gyro, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'd like to know if it's possible to get odometry and gyro data from a tablet or smart-phone and publish them in corresponding topics via Wifi for example ??

is it possible ?

if yes, is it difficult to do ?

Waiting for your answers.

Kind regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186646/odometry-and-gyro-replacement-for-my-new-robot-using-smart-phone-or-tablet-?/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this thread: http://answers.ros.org/question/10235/android-and-ros-communication-over-usb-instead-of-wifi/
But it's not enough to answer my question .
...
This ones helps more: http://answers.ros.org/question/189818/gps-data-from-smartphone/
http://wiki.ros.org/android_sensors_driver
wish it helps other Ros developers :)

---

Originally posted by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) with karma: 41 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0